# VB.NET Dim mySingle As Single = "" runtime error

Tags: vb.net, runtime

the compilation of
    Dim mySingle As Single = ""
is ok, but at runtime it throw an exception: Conversion from string "" to type 'Single' is not valid.

How could it be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String`s aren't `Single`s.

It compiles because you don't have `Option Strict`.
Without `Option Strict On` (either at the top of the file or preferably in project properties), all type-checking happens at runtime; there is no compile time type-safety.

You should ***ALWAYS*** use `Option Strict`.

Comment: Does C# allow you to assign a string to a single?  What value do you want the single to contain?

Comment: @dba: I assume that he's asking why it isn't a compile-time error.